# What is a good plugin for making a template that can be reused to make several objects on a single page?

Tags: plugins

I'm looking for a plugin or an idea that would allow a user to add a mini-post to a page. Each post would contain a .pdf, and a mini description.

I found Custom Field Template.. but I think once you fill it out once, you can't fill out another one for the same page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually wrote a plugin to accomplish this very thing ...

[WP Publication Archive](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-publication-archive/) is a plugin for WordPress that specifically adds the ability to create objects like this.  It introduces a custom post type for documents/publications that feature a downloadable file (i.e. PDF) with a title, description, tags, and authors taxonomy.

You can create multiple "collections" of publications by applying categories, then using a category filter within the shortcode on a page.  For example:

```
[wp-publication-archive categories=cat-1 /]
```

Would present a list of all publications in the "cat-1" category.

Here's an example of what an unstyled publication list (with only one download) would look like:

[image: Example output of WP Publication Archive]

Comment: Wow thanks a million! I just spent two hours working with Custom Fields Template and realized it's not remotely functional. :D Will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Great work. Was an easy install. I couldn't find any documentation on your short-codes besides this StackExchange post. I'd throw some up on the Wordpress site. :D Thanks again for all your hard-work!!!

Comment: All of the documentation is in the Readme file.  The shortcode itself is documented in the [FAQs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-publication-archive/faq/)

Comment: Hey EAMann, I added the ability to add thumbnails to your plugin. Would you like the snippet? If so.. how can I send it to you?

Comment: @Trip I'm intrigued ... post details on the plugin's [GitHub page ...](https://github.com/ericmann/WP-Publication-Archive)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this as widget in the sidebar I can recommend plugin [Mini Loops](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mini-loops/). It allows the selection of custom post types and offers an input field for a small configurable template with access to associated custom fields, too.

To avoid the unhandy standard custom field widget which comes with WP you may use a plugin like [Just Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/just-custom-fields/).

To create custom post types use plugins like [More Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-types/) or [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). These plugins can automatically create an edit page for the custom post type similiar to the edit page for posts.